# Plot points in DBSCAN

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have a set of points `[s1,s2,........,s27]`
then I calculate the similarity between points then the distance between the points that are in the csv file 'dataset' :( distance between si and sj =1- similarity ) and the similarity=((class affected by points i ∩ class affected by points j)/(class affected by points i ∪ class affected by points j)) ,finally, I get a matrix like that `distancematrix =[[ds1s1,ds1s2,...,ds1s27],[ds2s1,ds2s2,ds2s3,..ds2s27],.....[ds27s1,ds27s2,.....,ds27s27]]`
I input that distance matrix to DBSCAN algorithm. My code is as follows:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
points=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','s8','s9','s10','s11','512','s13','s14','s15','s16','s17','s18','s19','s20','s21','s22','s23','s24','s25','s26','s27'] 
Class = data ['Class'].values.tolist()
liste =[]
for n in range (0,len(points)):

    a="points_"+points[n]
    a= data[points[n]].values.tolist()
    b="ClassAffectedBy_"+points[n]
    b= []
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        if a [i] ==1:
            b.append([Class [i]])
    k = 'ClassAffectedByPoints_'+points[n]
    k = []
    for x in b:
        for y in x:
            k.append(y)
   #print(k)
    liste.append(k)

  dist = []

  for a in range (0,len(liste)):
      for b in range (0,len(liste)):

          Intersection=list(set(liste[a])& set(liste[b]))
          Union=list(set().union(liste[a],liste[b]))

          try:
            if a== b  :
              USim =1
              distance=0
              dist.append(distance)

            else:
              USim=len(Intersection)/len( Union)
              distance=1- (len(Intersection)/len( Union))
              dist.append(distance)
          except ZeroDivisionError :
              USim =0
              distance=1
              dist.append(distance)
distancematrix = [dist[x:x+27]for x in range(0,len(dist),27)]
```

this code is to calculate the distance between the points si and sj then I gave DBSCAN the distance matrix as follows:

```
#using default values, set metric to 'precomputed'
db = DBSCAN(eps= 0.75, min_samples = 2, metric='precomputed')
#check db
print(db)
db.fit(distancematrix)
#get labels
labels = db.labels_
print(labels)
#get number of clusters
no_clusters = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
print('No of clusters:', no_clusters)
print('Cluster 0 ', np.nonzero(labels == 0)[0])
print('Cluster 1 : ', np.nonzero(labels == 1)[0])
```

Now, I want to plot points and cluster them. I used this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
      for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
    for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
     if k == -1:
         # Black used for noise.
         col = [0, 0, 0, 1]
         class_member_mask = (labels == k)
         xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
         plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
         markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
         xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
         plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
         markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)
         plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % no_clusters)
         plt.show()
```

The problem is that when I execute this code, it returned a figure that does not contain all the points (26 points) - it returned to me only 20 points. And the points are not well grouped, I didn't understand this problem.